# Probability integral transform: Is it integral transform? Can it be for discrete distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, integral-transforms

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform)

> the probability integral transform or transformation relates to the result that data values that are modelled as being random variables from **any given continuous distribution** can be converted to random variables having a uniform distribution. This holds exactly provided that the distribution being used is the true distribution of the random variables; if the distribution is one fitted to the data the result will hold approximately in large samples.

1. I was wondering if the probability integral transform can be
   generalized to a random variable with a discrete distribution? Or any distribution?
2. Is the probability integral transform [an integral transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform) or
   some generalization of it?

   > an integral transform is any transform T of the following form: $$
   >         (Tf)(u) = \int \limits_{t_1}^{t_2} K(t, u)\, f(t)\, dt  $$

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 5):

I will answer the first question. When a random variable $X$ is discrete,
the range of its cumulative distribution function $F_X$ is countable,
and thus $F_X (X)$ could not be distributed as uniform $(0, 1)$. However, the
converse of your result still holds when $X$ is discrete. The generalized
inverse of $F_X$ (or quantile function) defined as
\begin{eqnarray*}
  F_X^{- 1} (u) & = & \inf_{} \{ x : F_X (x) \geqslant u \}
\end{eqnarray*}
satisfies the property that if $U$ is distributed uniform $(0, 1)$ then
$F_X^{- 1} (U)$ has the same distribution as $X$. For more details, see
chapter 7 in Shorack's 2000 book "Probability for statisticians".